# Put .xml file in pouchdb

Tags: javascript, xml, pouchdb

I am looking at Indexdb - `pouchdb`[attchments](https://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html), and I want to store `.xml` file as document, I have some xml file under in a path like `/xmls/file.xml` and I want to use javascript to store.do I missing somting in the documation? How do I load entire file on `pouch` or `indexDB` without using `data: ... //base 64` .

Comment: not clear if you want to store just the data or the whole file...or what you tried...or what part of the attachment documentation you don't understand. Suggest reviewing [ask]

Comment: 1 - all the file(if possible), not using base 64 encoding. 2- I don't know how to store an entire file so I don't know what to try. 3 - how to store an entire file, without using the 'data: '. I hope that know it is more clear.

Comment: why not just convert the data it contains to json first? seems like it would be easier to work with in the long run. As for storing ... there is no local file access

Comment: ammm let me try and I will post the result. thanks.